# ASP.NET core web API user registration unsuccessful

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I am building a Web API using ASP.NetCore 1.1 and Ef core 1.1 with MySql as my database. I am following (https://fullstackmark.com/post/10/user-authentication-with-angular-and-asp-net-core) tutorial to implement user registration.

I have created two models:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // Extended Properties
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class Stakeholder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdentityId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Identity { get; set; }  // navigation property

}
```

I have also a RegistrationViewModel:

```
[Validator(typeof(RegistrationViewModelValidator))]
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And it's validator:

```
public class RegistrationViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RegistrationViewModel>
{
    public RegistrationViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(vm => vm.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email cannot be empty");
        RuleFor(vm => vm.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Password cannot be empty");
        RuleFor(vm => vm.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("FirstName cannot be empty");
        RuleFor(vm => vm.LastName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("LastName cannot be empty");
    }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class WebAPIDataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public WebAPIDataContext(DbContextOptions<WebAPIDataContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User_Task> User_Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stakeholder> Stakeholders { get; set; }


}
```

Additionally I also have written a mappings class as shown in the tutorial:

```
   public class ViewModelToEntityMappingProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public ViewModelToEntityMappingProfile()
        {
              CreateMap<RegistrationViewModel,ApplicationUser>().ForMember(au => au.UserName, map => map.MapFrom(vm => vm.Email));
        }
    }
```

My complete startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Vision_backlog_backend.Models;
using Vision_backlog_backend.Repository;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Vision_backlog_backend
{
    public class Startup
    {

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddDbContext<WebAPIDataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"), 
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Vision_backlog_backend"));
            });


            services.AddScoped<IProfileRepository, ProfileRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUser_TaskRepository, User_TaskRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IFeatureRepository, FeatureRepository>();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            });


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            // global policy - assign here or on each controller
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


            app.UseMvc();

            // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwagger();

            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

At last I have created AccountsController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    private readonly WebAPIDataContext _appDbContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AccountsController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IMapper mapper, WebAPIDataContext appDbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    // POST api/accounts
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(model);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

        await _appDbContext.Stakeholders.AddAsync(new Stakeholder { IdentityId = userIdentity.Id });
        await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new OkObjectResult("Account created");
    }
}
```

I did my first migration and updated the database, tables are created. If I start the server and hit localhost:4784/api/Accounts I get a status code 500 and nothing is created in the database. I also put a debug point in my controller but it does not hit it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `services.AddAutoMapper();` in startup.cs but it was still giving compilation errors, so after couple of hours of searching I realized I had to install `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`.

After this the above code works and user is registered successfully.